# Insert HTML Attribute with Beautiful Soup

Tags: python, beautifulsoup

I have a simple need: I wish to insert an attribute into a HTML section using Beautiful Soup which reflects into the webpage.

For example, for the HTML Code:

```
<input type="submit" name="name1">
```

I have the BeautifulSoup as:

```
from BeautifulSoup import BeautifulSoup
soup = BeautifulSoup('<input type="submit" name="name1">')
getElementByName = soup.find(attrs={'name':'name1'})
# getElementByName.insert method does not reflect the insertion on the webpage
```

And I wish to mimic the following Javascript method for Beautiful Soup:

```
document.getElementByName("name1").setAttribute("id", "id1");
```

I believe Beautiful Soup cannot do this, because its just a XML/HTML parser. But just throwing it out there, if anyone knows the answer?

Thanks,
Amit

Answer (score 2):

[Documentation](http://www.crummy.com/software/BeautifulSoup/documentation.html#Modifying%20the%20Parse%20Tree) is a great thing

Yes, you can modify the parse tree. In this case probably something like:

```
getElementByName("name1")["id"] = "id1"
```